# Authorize.net FDS/Success

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-webhooks

When a user runs 6 transactions straight that are declined (fake or unusable card), the 6th flags as “Do not authorize” and moves to “FDS” for review. When it does this, it is returning a “successful purchase” webhook to our application, resulting in digital merchandise being provided when payment isn’t processed but infact only flagged as fraud.  How do we stop such from happening?

Followed auth.net flow

Comment: Can you post the webhook payload just in case it's useful for debugging purposes?